# Reading a PDF Document in Android

Tags: java, android, api, pdf

this is my first question or rather Questions. I am in my last semester this college and Reading PDF is one of the components that im developing for my thesis.

I have been reading questions about reading a pdf document but there are no solid answer. I want to know **what are the ways to read a PDF document?** what i have read that there are API's available that can read PDF Document like PDFBox, [muPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/), and [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). I have not seen any other API's but this is what i have read on other posts.

The problem here is first **PDFBox** i read that PDFBox can not be use because of AWT Dependencies and android is has no AWT and Swing related classes. PDFBox is out of the question. **muPDF** i have not read anything about muPDF, it was recommended to me but i want to know if it is usable to read PDF Document. **iText** this is the most common API that i encounter in PDF and android related questions. the problem here is its **License**?(Correct me if im wrong) I have not tried any of this 3 yet because i want know if there are another solutions beside this 3.

Other than APIs, i think **PDF Reader Applications** can be used too if im not mistaken? if it can be used then **HOW?**. I'm not looking for a Code but a explanation of how you did it and how you implemented it in your application.

i have thought another way but i do not know if this is possible. how about convert PDF Document into a .txt or .doc file? inside the android. it would be like when i load a PDF document inside the android a Code will convert that PDF Document into a .txt / .doc file and the application will search and extract text from the .txt / .doc file rather then the PDF Document.

if you are asking WHY do i need this kind of component, because i'm working on a application that would **SEARCH** and **EXTRACT** text from a PDF Document using Android.

This is my questions:

1. What are the ways to read a PDF Document in Android?
2. What are your experiences in using this kind of method?
3. How did you do it using this kind of method(just a flow/explanation would do)?
4. If the method has a License what would be the problem in the future?

PS: Correct me if i'm wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very iText specific answer so it does not answer all your questions, but it may still be of help to you.

> What are the ways to read a PDF Document in Android?

I use the iText java bindings (Keep reading to find out about LGPL licensing)

> What are your experiences in using this kind of method?

Great! It covers all things PDF related. (Older versions may be a little different)

> How did you do it using this kind of method(just a flow/explanation would do)?

I assume this question is related to the "other way" that you thought of so it is not relevant to the iText PDF library?

> If the method has a License what would be the problem in the future?

I still encourage you to use the updated version of iText, however if you use iText version 2.1.7 or older it falls under the old LGPL license, and has far more free reign and is more suitable for commercial or private/closed use with no real problems. From what I can tell all the functionality you are after is available in version 2.1.7 version.

The AGPL license for current version of iText is pretty decent, from what I understand you do need to publish your program under a similar license and make the code freely available to others (it would pay to check the details though), if sharing code is not a problem then the latest version of iText is worth looking into.

---

References:

LGPL License: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html

iText AGPL License: http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/agpl.php

Comment: can you give some idea about how to use iText in applications.

Comment: Thank you for the time answering my question sorifiend. about question 3 'I want know how did you use iText in application' as SahilmahajanMJ said. Ill surely check iText out. Thank you again.

Comment: by the way, about the licensing what if my application was uploaded in 'Google Play' would it be taken down because of itext licensing?

Comment: Did you mean how to work with iText? In that case the best way to learn iText is to buy the book "iText in Action", but you can also find resources elsewhere, I found these two sites very helpful: http://api.itextpdf.com/ and http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php

Comment: Or did you mean how do you add the iText library with an android app? loading an external library is easy, a quick google search of `use java library in android` returned this page: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/jar-for-android/ scroll down a bit to see the process

Comment: I have not had any experience with "Google Play", but if you are charging people to use your application then you break the AGPL license for newer versions of iText (unless you buy a commercial license), however from what I can tell under the older versions of iText with the LGPL license you may sell your software, I encourage you to read the license info I have linked above and confirm this for yourself, the LGPL license is pretty short and doesn't take long to read through.

Comment: One more thing, keep in mind that the older version of iText with the LGPL license may not work with some of the examples I linked in my comment above, you would need to track down the older API to see what can and cannot be done, or simply give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks again for replying. I will read the links later if i have time later. Thank you again you are a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I was also working on an Android Application, where i need to open PDF files in my android application. First i thought about doing this by using foreign API's. I tried to used mupdf, but it was not a good experience.

Then our team leader suuggested me to first install a pdf viewer application in your device and then use code to open pdf through the installed pdf viewer application.

You can easily download pdf viewer application from gogle play, then you can use the following code to open the pdf in your application,

```
                File file = new File("/sdcard/MyPDFfile.pdf");
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
```

This code will automatically look for the installed pdf application in your device and will pass the intent to that application to open the pdf file.

Comment: This is the android way. Not what he is asking for. He needs to EXTRACT text.